# .ASPX: How do I restrict web access to logged on users only?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, iis, .aspxauth

► **Problem**: Anyone can access a webpage, but I only want logged in users to be authorized to access it.

---

**Background**:

- Web Server = IIS 8
- Server OS = Windows Server 2012
- Framework = .NET 4.5
- Environment = .\WebFolder\logon.aspx, .\WebFolder\inside.html
- Website = Simple logon page ("logon.aspx") that guards an html page ("inside.html").
- Users = External people (ie, non-intranet)

Sample URLs:

```
    A. "www.webpage.com/logon.aspx"
    B. "www.webpage.com/inside.html"
```

Desired Outcome:

Everyone can access the "logon.aspx" page

Only logged on users can access the "inside.html" page

Any direct attempts to access "B" will trigger a redirect to "A"

No additional use of program code

**Prior Attempts**:
I've been fiddling with the web.config file (authentication & authorization), but to no avail (501 Server Error, 401 Authorization Error, Runtime Application Error).

---

Web.Config File:
    `<system.web>`
`<authentication>`
`<forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="logon.aspx" protection="All" timeout="1" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="false" />`
`</authentication>`
`<authorization></authorization>`
`</system.web>`

---

Bottom line: I'm sure this is a very basic/easy thing to configure, it's just that I haven't been able to do it so far. Plus, I do not want to write any additional code in order to accomplish a seemingly fundamental task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try renaming your logon.aspx page to login.aspx? Or alternatively, add a new forms node to the authentication node in the web.config file like:  <forms loginUrl="~/logon.aspx" />. Could you post the relevant sample of your web.config file?

Comment: @SeanOB: New Attempt: Changed "logon.aspx" to "login.aspx". Result = Failed (no change). Please check above for the new "web.config" section. Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll need to use a membership provider, or some such thing. The basic idea would be to flag users as logged on or not. A simple implementation would be to check in the page's load method (presumably under the correct postback occurrences): 
`If Not IsLoggedIn() Then Response.Redirect("somepage.aspx") End If`

Comment: @SeanOB, Thanks, guys. I think I have a solution for this .aspx to .html file restriction (after 7+ hours :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out (after 7 hours). It requires four things (based on the example file structure):

---

## 1. Using the `FormsAuthentication` module

VS2012 → Project → Your credentials/authentication code → Use `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLogin(_var1_, _var2_)` instead of `Response.Redirect(inside.html)`

---

## 2. Adding a new node in the `web.config` file

```
<system.webServer><handlers><add name="HTMLHandler" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" /></handlers>
```

---

## 3. Including the 'defaultUrl' attribute in the `Forms` tag

```
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="logon.aspx" defaultUrl="inside.html" protection="All" timeout="1" path="/" slidingExpiration="false" requireSSL="false" />
```

---

## 4. Adding a location tag authorization restriction to the 'web.config' file

```
<location path="inside.html"><system.web><authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization></system.web></location>
```

---

See my comments (below) for an explanation of each of these four pieces.

Comment: #1. You need to use the FormsAuthentication object because it passes the  credentials to the server. This is important, because it's the server (not the application) that manages the .html page. The Response.Redirect command fails to do this.

Comment: #2. You must add the HTMLHandler to the `web.config` file, because it tells IIS to give your .net application control of the .html page's connectivity. This is critical (since Step#4 would not work without it).

Comment: #3. It's important to add the `defaultUrl` attribute to the `forms` tag so that the FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLogin will always arrive at your destination ("inside.html"). When the `ReturnUrl` variable isn't specified, then the RedirectFromLogin command will navigate to this `DefaultUrl`. The `loginUrl` value in Step#2 becomes the `ReturnUrl` value upon failed authentication.

Comment: #4. You must create this location path authorization in order for the system to prevent unauthorized access to your html file ("inside.html"). The `deny users="?"` item tells the system to block unauthorized access to your restricted html page.